# Ternary operators returning "true : false". Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ternary-operator

Coworker had me grep for the string "true : false" through our project, and I found a lot of ternary operators returning explicit true or false. For example:

```
return this.state == Cursor.CLOSED ? true : false;
```

Not just in our project, but plenty of modules/libraries do this. It seems redundant to me, since the author could have just written it like this:

```
return this.state == Cursor.CLOSED;
```

Is it defensive coding against some gotcha in Javascript? Or just to be explicit with what you are returning?

Comment: that seems to simply return true if the state is closed? [What's wrong with that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx)? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I think he's asking that it could just be `return this.state == Cursor.CLOSED;`

Comment: To me it seems uneccessary, if `this.state == Cursor.CLOSED` it's already true ?

Comment: In this case, I'd guess the author didn't realize that he / she could just return the result of the comparison. However, `return foo || bar ? true : false;` is very different from just `return foo || bar`.

Comment: @Vic, yes that is what I'm asking. Seems like the ternary is unnecessary for comparisons that would return true or false anyways.

Comment: I think he is wondering why it's not just "return (this.state == Cursor.CLOSED);". That would make more sense to me and should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't think there's a benefit to returning true/false, probably just a bad author :)

Comment: @Vic, but I noticed this pattern in plenty of popular/large development libraries. Socket.io does this, as does Amazon's AWS API, and mongodb.

Comment: @RossHettel, do you have an example of where socket.io does this? https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js

Comment: @Vic, we have an older version of the library we're using, 0.9.16. Here's one place: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/0.9/dist/socket.io.js#L3030

Comment: @RossHettel: In that case, it's being used as a more prominent version of `!!`. The value wasn't already a boolean — `String.prototype.match` returns an array.

Comment: @Chuck, ah good catch. That usage makes sense then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it defensive coding against some gotcha in Javascript?

No. `==` does always return a boolean value.

The conditional is completely redundant, and considered a bad practise. [Simplify it!](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs111/spring00/lectures/boolean-simplification.html)

Comment: Also, if you need to convert to a boolean in javascript, the common way to do it is to negate it twice i.e. `!!nonBool`.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite unnecessary, but it's a pretty common mistake† in many languages. Because the equality operator is used almost exclusively in conditions, some less-knowledgeable programmers don't know and more experienced programmers occasionally forget that it can actually be used for its value. There has never been any major JavaScript implementation that had a quirk that made this necessary.

† "Mistake" feels unkind here, since the code is correct, just needlessly verbose. But I think you know what I mean.